# why does the Integer.paseInt() algorithm calculate negative result finally in sun jdk

Tags: java, algorithm, java-6

In jdk source,I have some questions about the Integer's parseInt(String str,int radix)  algorithm.let's see the code source below.

```
        multmin = limit / radix;
        while (i < len) {
            // Accumulating negatively avoids surprises near MAX_VALUE
            digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++),radix);
            if (digit < 0) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            if (result < multmin) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            result *= radix;
            if (result < limit + digit) {
                throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
            }
            result -= digit;
        }
```

why it is ***result -= digit*** rather than result +=digit? I am confused.

Comment: Did you see the line `return negative ? result : -result;` about two lines below the snippet you've quoted?

Comment: Did you see the comment 'accumulating negatively avoids surprises near MAX_VALUE'?

Comment: so when the num is negatigve,limit  varaiable is Integer.MIN_VALUE,and the num is positive,the limit varaiable is -Integer.MAX_VALUE, why?I am confused too. could you specify the algorithm or some articles' links?

Comment: @Mooner_guo - I doubt that such articles exist.  Instead, what you need to do is to **think very hard** about what is going on here.  In this case, you need start with / from a solid understanding of the properties of 2's complement binary integer representation. (Understanding deep things generally requires deep thought ... not reading simple explanations.)

Comment: @StephenC In this case, the 2's complement representation is the cause of the asymmetrical range for positive and negative numbers, but the reason for the approach in `parseInt` is the asymmetrical range itself. If Java had a type that ranged from [-15, 5] then a parse function for that type would take the same approach as here if they don't want to have special or duplicated logic for positive and negative numbers

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - I am aware of that.  That's why I said "start with", and "think very hard".  The real point of my comment is to encourage the OP to think, rather than asking for someone else to do the thinking for him.

Comment: @StephenC Ok, agreed with that sentiment

Answer (score 7):

The code has a comment: "Accumulating negatively avoids surprises near MAX_VALUE"

As the number is parsed, the code adds the digits to the accumulator variable `result`.

Now the author wanted to write the code to build up the number in the accumulator only once for both positive and negative numbers.

Then when it is done, it adds the sign to it; if there was a minus character in front of the number, the result will be made negative, otherwise positive.

The problem is that the number range for integers is not symmetrical for positive and negative numbers. The smallest negative number that fits into an `int` is -2147483648 but the largest positive number if 2147483647.

If the number in the `result` local variable was kept positive, it wouldn't be possible to parse the negative number -2147483648.

That's why the code keeps it negative until the end - because the range of negative numbers is large enough to hold all positive numbers, while the range of positive numbers is one number too small to hold all negative numbers.